# Radio Signal Coverage Standard for GIS

Tags: file-formats

Is there any **Standard** data format for Radio Signal Coverage for GIS?

Something like GPX or KML (or other XML/JSON/etc-based) for routes, tracks, POI, etc. But for signal strength, base radio stations and other.

Or is there any **Best Practice** for processing, storage and interchange this type of data for Computer Systems?

#### My case

I want to (1) "impose" tracks from GPX/KML files "on the map" with signal coverage and then (2) select those sections of routes where the signal is lower than the specified value; I want to do it programmatically with popular programming or scripting lang in offline (not with any SaaS).

#### Observations

I know several websites that allow you to select some Country/Network and view result on top of OSM, Google and other maps. Do they use the same data format for this? Or, in each case, do they adapt different input data to the map elements (lines polygons, etc)? In this case, in what form they receive input data from MNOs? Or not from MNOs?

Comment: Something like this?
https://sites.google.com/site/androiddevelopmentproject/home/rf-signal-tracker

Comment: @pedja-yt9tp, I will study this app. I speak about maps like this one: http://www.stevelarkins.freeuk.com/images/M0SBF_coverage3.jpg

Comment: @pedja-yt9tp, looking for image for your answer I found informative post about how to create coverage maps with propagation: https://ham.stackexchange.com/q/1921/15747